# Unity Tweak Tools missing schema in 14.04

Tags: unity

When I try to start up Unity Tweak Tool in 14.04, it throws up a window that says:

"The following schema is missing:

com.canonical.unity.webapps

In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you install the necessary packages."

I have no removed this package, I only turned them off in the Privacy settings.  However, looking in Synaptic doesn't show these to even try to reinstall them.

I have no idea why these would be missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

I removed a package I don't remember and this problem occurred to me too. To reinstall this webapp I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common
```

and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Turns out, uninstalling the Amazon app actually uninstalls this. Hm, who knew? Thanks for catching this.