# Schemas missing - Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, webapps, unity-tweak-tool

I understand this is very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450025/unity-tweak-tools-missing-schema-in-14-04) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449943/unity-tweak-tool-fails-to-start-with-the-error-com-canonical-unity-webapps-sche), but none of the answers there have worked for me.
When trying to install the packages mentioned in those questions, apt-get throws up the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install the dependencies mentioned there, I just find more and more dependencies. Synaptic Package Manager gives error messages when I select 'Fix Broken Packages'. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance, and please comment if you need more information.

**UPDATE**:
Running `apt-cache policy webapp-container unity-webapps-service` gave the following result:

```
webapp-container:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.23+14.04.20140428-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.23+14.04.20140428-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.23+14.04.20140414-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
unity-webapps-service:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5.0~+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.5.0~+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**UPDATE 2**:
Version information:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**UPDATE 3**:
When trying to install `unity-webapps-service` using aptitude instead of apt-get:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin{a} liboxideqtcore0{a} liboxideqtquick0{ab} 
  libqt5feedback5{a} libqt5multimedia5{ab} libqt5organizer5{ab} 
  libqt5positioning5{ab} libunity-webapps0{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin{ab} 
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin{ab} 
  qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin{ab} unity-webapps-qml{a} 
  unity-webapps-service webapp-container{ab} webbrowser-app{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 103 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 webapp-container : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 libqt5organizer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
                                 Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 webbrowser-app : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 libqt5positioning5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 liboxideqtquick0 : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
                                           Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:           
1)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                          
2)      liboxideqtcore0 [Not Installed]                               
3)      liboxideqtquick0 [Not Installed]                              
4)      libqt5feedback5 [Not Installed]                               
5)      libqt5multimedia5 [Not Installed]                             
6)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                              
7)      libqt5positioning5 [Not Installed]                            
8)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                             
9)      qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin [Not Installed]                 
10)     qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin [Not Installed]          
11)     qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin [Not Installed]              
12)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin [Not Installed]
13)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]       
14)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                             
15)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                         
16)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                              
17)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                                



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

**UPDATE 4**:
The output of `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 is a virtual package provided by:
  libqt5qml5 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 [Not candidate version]
  libqt5qml5 5.2.1-3ubuntu15 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1' has no installation candidate
```

The output of `sudo apt-get install unity-webapp-container`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-webapp-container
```

**UPDATE 5**:
Output of `apt-cache policy libqt5qml5`:

```
libqt5qml5:
  Installed: 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1
  Candidate: 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.2.1-3ubuntu15 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install webapp-container`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 webapp-container : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1
                    Depends: unity-webapps-qml but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: webbrowser-app (= 0.23+14.04.20140428-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: run & post - `apt-cache policy webapp-container unity-webapps-service`

Comment: @doug I have updated my post with the output.

Comment: Well then try to specifically install unity-webapps-service as in `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service`  (- are you running Ubuntu 14.04 or something else? - `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @doug Trying to install `unity-webapps-service` gives me the error at the top of my question! And yes, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Try switching to the Main server in Software & Updates, then try again. if it fails please post here or in a pastebin the complete terminal output start to finish

Comment: @doug Switching to the main server has seemed to make no difference at all. Again, apt-get gives exactly the same error message when trying to install `unity-webapps-service`. Here it is in a pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11763213/

Comment: Very odd, try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update` Then ck. this package,  `apt-cache policy libunity-webapps0` if avail. see if it will install

Comment: @doug `libunity-webapps0` isn't installed, and I can't install it either. Similar error messages.

Comment: Can you install anything? (pick something from software-center).  If so then install aptitude and use it instead of apt-get, usually aptitude is a bit more verbose.

Comment: @doug SuperTux 2 installed fine from the Ubuntu Software Centre. I've installed aptitude and this is what it says when I run `sudo aptitude install unity-webapps-service`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11764338/

Comment: @doug said in the chat: It's that ppa you are using that has updated some qt libs that aren't compatible with the Ubuntu packages you are trying to install. So either live without them & the tweak package or use ppa-purge on the ppa.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1` and `sudo apt-get install unity-webapp-container` in exact this order and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: Please answer my comment, otherwise your points were in vain.

Comment: @A.B. Sorry, I didn't have access to my computer yesterday. I'll try and answer your comment as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok, thx and the next one `apt-cache policy libqt5qml5`

Comment: And `sudo ap-get install webapp-container`

Comment: And give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: If as mentioned you don't wish to purge that ppa then try extracting the schema from unity-webapps-service package, placing in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ , recompiling glib schemas & see if unity tweak suffers in use.  Was in the 2nd of your links - http://askubuntu.com/questions/449943/unity-tweak-tool-fails-to-start-with-the-error-com-canonical-unity-webapps-sche  answer by jackyzy823

Comment: Common, we have three days …

Comment: @A.B. I have updated my post.

Comment: @doug What exactly does purging the PPA do? I'm happy to do it as long as it doesn't have any negative effects... Also, how do I extract the schema? Sorry, I'm still somewhat a noob!

Comment: could you remind me which ppa, I can't find the chat room so have forgotten. If you purge the ppa then you'll lose whatever you got from enabling it in the first place. If you want try the extract end around I'd prefer ubuntu forums as it's more interactive. You could always summerize an answer here if it proves suitable

Comment: @doug Found the chat room - I had to “show frozen rooms". https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25123/2015/6/23

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll risk it and leave a response.

A main problem seems to be the PPA ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable. With this PPA you can't use the needed version of `libqt5qml5`

Therefore remove the PPA with the following command.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service
```

---

*Where is the problem?*

The command `apt-cache policy libqt5qml5` returns the following. The PPA ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable installs a newer version (5.3.0) for `libqt5qml5`
but `qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1` needs exact version 5.2.1.

```
libqt5qml5:
  Installed: 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1
  Candidate: 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.0-3ubuntu13~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.2.1-3ubuntu15 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

*Side effects*

Purging the PPA downgrades the packages installed by  the PPA. If a downgrade isn't possible, because a package only exists in this PPA, the package will be removed. The configuration files of the package still exists in your system after the removal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27707/discussion-on-answer-by-a-b-schemas-missing-unity-tweak-tool).