# Neon and Kubuntu backports together? or not?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Is it a good idea, or a terrible one, to have both repositories together? Do the play along or do they conlict?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a good idea to have them both. Sometimes the Kubuntu backports PPA will install upgraded versions of dependencies which will result in broken packages(see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862706/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-this-specific-situation/862775#862775) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639590/schemas-missing-unity-tweak-tool/668336#668336)) because some packages require downgraded versions to function correctly.

Comment: Agreed. This is true of PPAs which provide big software stacks like KDE or GNOME in general. It's probably a better idea to stick to Ubuntu interim (6-month) releases and use Snappy, Flatpak and/or AppImage if you want to update software past the official versions. Otherwise you risk dependency hell (these formats avoid the problem).